# Prove that $\Bbb Z_2(\alpha)=\Bbb Z_2(\beta)$ .

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Consider the polynomials $x^3+x^2+1,x^3+x+1$ over $\Bbb Z_2$ which have roots say $\alpha,\beta $ respectively. Prove that $\Bbb Z_2(\alpha)=\Bbb Z_2(\beta)$  .

Since both $x^3+x^2+1,x^3+x+1$ are irreducible so $\Bbb Z_2(\alpha)\cong \Bbb Z_2[x]/<x^3+x^2+1>$ and $\Bbb Z_2(\beta)\cong \Bbb Z_2[x]/<x^3+x+1>$.

The elements of $\Bbb Z_2(\alpha)$ are $\{a+b\alpha +c\alpha^2 \mid a,b,c\in \Bbb Z_2\}$. Also, the elements of $\Bbb Z_2(\beta)$ are $\{a+b\beta+c\beta^2 \mid a,b,c\in \Bbb Z_2\}$.

How to show they are equal?

Comment: you want to prove equality or isomorphism?

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial of $1/\alpha$ is $x^3+x+1$, so 
$$\mathbb{Z}(\alpha)=\mathbb{Z}(1/\alpha)\equiv\mathbb{Z}(\beta)$$

Comment: You mean $\Bbb Z_2$ instead of $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: I did not get that at all

Comment: Why is $\Bbb Z(\alpha)=\Bbb Z(\frac{1}{\alpha})$

Comment: $1/\alpha=\alpha^2+\alpha$

Comment: It is a finite group, so $1/\alpha$ is always going to be a polynomial of $\alpha$, and vice versa.